# Can I be denied a tourist visa to China?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, china, canadian-citizens

I'm a Canadian citizen born in Iraq. I came to Canada at a young age. Could I be denied a tourist visa to China? The visa agency said I might be. What's the likelihood of this happening?

Comment: this morning at the visa agency, the guy next to me (who sounded like he was from the UK) was denied a visa because he had visited Pakistan. He was complaining very loud, because it said nowhere that he was supposed to inform them that he had visited Pakistan. They made him reapply. (he was loud, I could hear the whole thing) My guess is that countries you recently visited may be a more relevant issue.

Comment: @PatrickT: That's surprising. China and Pakistan are great friends. But the Chinese visa process is not designed to be transparent, even less so than for many other countries.

Comment: @hippietrail, yes, I've applied for visas to China on several occasions and they never twice asked for the same set of documents...

Answer (score 42):

Any citizen of any country could be denied a visa by any other country, there are no guarantees.  A Visa Service will inform you of this upfront to avoid any legal issues later, if by chance you are one of the unlucky few.

In your particular situation, the chances of a denied visa are likely low.  But we don't know your situation (work, background, income, etc) to be certain.

Answer (score 10):

Quite likely, perhaps a 20% chance. Despite what others here are saying:

- Use an agency, because Chinese visas are usually obtained via a "connection". Don't go and apply by yourself.
- Your passport will probably state your place of birth as Iraq, and that's a huge red flag to them (no pun intended), unlike if you were born in Russia or a similarly "harmless" country.

Comment: Had a similar experience. Went to an embassy on my own, couldn't get anything done. Went to a visa agency with the very same documents, no issue.

Comment: @Robus Really now? Here in Zurich you just go to the consulate, hand in the documents listed on the website, and they'll call you when the visa's ready. What embassy did you go to?

Comment: @Crazydre The bureau in Beijing where you can apply for a visa while within China. Couldn't get a Tourist/Transit visa even though eligible.

Comment: @Robus that's the police, which is a different department

Comment: @Robus Embassies are missions abroad. Who says the "difficulty" is equal to that with the domestic authorities? My experience, both with Afghanistan, China and Russia, are the polar opposite

Comment: "Use an agency" and "connection" seriously???

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, I concur on this point. I've applied in the UK (successfully) for visas using both methods (agency / embassy), and the agency had an advantage. Their applications were streamlined. I confirmed this myself by checking appointment availability at the embassy (~1 week wait time). The agency got my application dealt with the next day. This was something specific to the agency: there was no next day service available through the embassy (even for extra money). The person at the agency had a contact at the embassy that they sent all their applications to.

Comment: "Use an electrician" and "skill/experience" seriously???

Comment: Interesting... it's been a few years since I visited China. I applied for the tourist visa myself, directly, in London and had no problem whatsoever.

Comment: The China embassies and consulates in Canada have not granted visas for a number of years. There are official centres (the one in Toronto is at 393 University Ave. on the 15th floor). You get your ducks in a row and go in- make sure you have copies of whatever you need (eg. flight booking or whatever it says you should bring), the photocopier there is temperamental and expensive.They triage at the front desk and check your paperwork and from there it's usually just waiting until your number comes up to submit the documents. You pick up your passport some days later. Connections?? It's not 1975

Comment: People who live far outside the area can use agents (BOC was doing it, not sure if they still do) but it adds a bunch of time (not to mention cost) and they don't always get it right.

Comment: What do you mean by "usually"? I've obtained Chinese visas 4 times in 3 countries, and though I never know exactly what's going on I've never needed or heard of needing a "connection". Are you saying this is usual for Iraqis or for everybody?

Comment: Gosh, all the 'connection' people, you've misunderstood. It is not the you who needs have "connections". It's the guy at the embassy/agency/whereverYouPutYourDocumentsAt. What's relevant happens behind the scenes, without your agenda. If you go to an agency that's for some reason has bad reputation in view of the Chinese goverment, your case will have much worse chances to succeed, even if your documents are clean. Also, "the connections" does not necessarily mean mafia/etc. It may be simply knowledge whom to send the documents to get it done faster/easier, similarly to credit agencies.

Comment: Re "faster/easier" - and that in turn does not have to mean "illegal" or "against procedures". Sometimes, procedures don't exist and it's only an authority and their word and good humour. Sometimes, procedures do exist, but leave some leeways. For example, let's say there's no strict requirement for them to inform you what went wrong. Get a response "denied" with no word of explanation instead of "not all required documents were presented" and you're done. On the other hand, if the agency knows whom to talk with, they will hear that form X was sent in 2013 version instead of newest from 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, avoid visa agencies, as they often charge fees and/or present the paperwork incorrectly.

Secondly, it is very unusual for Chinese tourist visas to be denied for Western citizens. If you hand in all the documents required, it's usually an automatic approval (this is my experience with Russian visas, and Chinese ones are supposedly even easier)

Go onto [this site](http://www.visaforchina.org/), select the application centre nearest to you, and follow the step-by-step instructions. You can also apply via post, convenient if the nearest application centre is far from you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66322/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-can-i-be-denied-a-tourist-visa-to-china).